# Single.TryParse always failing

Tags: c#, .net

I've been looking at a calculator for a friend, and we're having some difficulties with Single.TryParse method.

According to MSDN, the following code should work:

```
float j;
if (Single.TryParse("1.5", out j))
    Console.WriteLine(j);
else
    Console.WriteLine("String could not be parsed.");
```

But it always outputs String could not be parsed. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

This is using Visual Studio 2015, community edition - I believe that to use .NET 4.6?

Other code I've tried:

```
String value = "1.5";
float number;
NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
if (Single.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
    Console.WriteLine(number);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Error parsing number");
```

Comment: I've set the locale in similar experiments to en-GB, and set the other format-oriented thing to something equally appropriate.

Comment: I can't replicate with either a `.` or a `,`, so I suspect you have some custom culture setting that does not use `.` for either the decimal or thousands separator.

Comment: Could you add this line to your code and tell us what is the output? _Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);_

Comment: I've added the CultureInfo now - see OP. Assuming using the TryParse overload will override the system culture info?

Comment: @XtrmJosh consider using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: I have tried your second example and it works as expected.

Comment: That's odd, it's working on my second dev box, also. I wonder why it's not on the first... Will investigate and update as appropriate. If you've any thoughts, do let me know :)

Comment: Some people change Windows formatting options and those are picked by .Net... Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` unless you really need to parse user's input (in which case failing to parse is probably appropriate).